# Apache redirecting to http after log in in ShinyProxy

Tags: apache, authentication

I have sucessfully set up an Apache HTTPD web server and ShinyProxy instance so that I can access a set of shiny apps over https (on server runing amazon linux).

When I visit

https://www.example.com

I (as expected) get the  login page provided by the web applicaiton (shiny proxy). For now this is set up to use simple authentication.

However when I log in (which is sucessful) the page i am viewing redirects me to http://example.com . I need it to stay on https especially because google auth will not allow you to redirect to an http page.

I think the problem is probably with my  apache config file. The relevant part is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile <path to crt>
    SSLCertificateKeyFile <path to key>
    SSLCertificateChainFile <path to bundle>
    
    # This block is needed for the interal workings off the app
      <Proxy *>
        Allow from localhost
      </Proxy>
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
     RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:3600/$1 [P,L]
     RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
     RewriteRule /(.*) http://localhost:3600/$1 [P,L]
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:3600/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3600/
     ProxyRequests Off
     ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone have any thoughts about how I might fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, and so am providing the answer in case anyone else is still stuck.

1. If you are still having this problem for me the issue was the home page image that I was including in my ShinyProxy application.yml file was served over http, so Apache was forcing the whole website back to http. Exchanging the default image for one served over https fixed the problem.
2. Additionally in the latest version of ShinyProxy (2.4+) you need to include in application.yml under the server block the line
   `forward-headers-strategy: native`